# MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory using web.config in SP 2010 Claims and FBA

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Thanks in advance. I've a SP 2010 farm. It has two front-end web applications,

- WebApp1 (boxname = box1.domain.com) uses default windows authentication mode,
- WebApp2 (boxname = box2.domain.com) uses Claims based authentication using FBA by LDAP Authentication,

I developed a WCF service application and it has two services. One of the service uses MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory and running fine from both the web applications. Another one is custom web.config based service and not working from WebApp2, not even can publish metadata.

My question is I don't want to use MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory and like to do the same thing using a web.config file. Can it be possible? If possible, can anyone please help me to do that?

Few points to take into consideration - 
- Wcf files are basic "Hello World" type application,
- I'm using WCFTestClient to test the services,
- IIS Authentication for WebApp2 includes Anonymous, Forms, Windows is enabled, rest are disabled,

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write code to programmatically add the base address since the actual address of your service will depend on site collection etc. There's no way to dynamically assign the address using the config file.

Having said that, you could deploy your service outside of SharePoint by changing the managed paths for your web application and then deploying directly to IIS. The drawback of course is that you won't have access to SPContext and the SharePoint security model.